# Tramp hanging on writing or opening file

Tags: debugging, tramp

Tramp consistently hangs, for me, when opening or writing a remote file.  None of the ‘why is Tramp hanging...?’ resources I've found seem to address my situation.

What's odd is that this *used* to work fine – something has changed to break this, on the client side I think, and I can't work out what.

The problem appears to happen only for version-controlled remote files (in my case Mercurial).  See below.

---

I open a remote file `/scp:helium:foo.c`, and get Tramp debug messages like (this is with `tramp-verbose` set to 10):

```
Tramp: Opening connection for helium using scp...
Tramp: Sending command ‘exec ssh   -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none helium’
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...done
Tramp: Found remote shell prompt on ‘helium’
Tramp: Opening connection for helium using scp...done
Tramp: Inserting ‘/scp:helium:/home/norman/checkouts/itm/sso/misc/ldap-info-wrapper.c’...
Tramp: Encoding remote file ‘/scp:helium:/home/norman/checkouts/itm/sso/misc/ldap-info-wrapper.c’ with ‘(gzip <%s | openssl enc -base64)’...done
Tramp: Decoding local file ‘/var/folders/f5/vh0d0ls94_j5s4bv49sz90s40000gn/T/tramp.4wIIyB.c’ with ‘(lambda (beg end) (base64-decode-region beg end) (let ((coding-system-for-write (quote binary)) (coding-system-for-read (quote binary))) (apply (quote tramp-call-process-region) (quote (tramp-file-name scp nil nil helium nil /home/norman/checkouts/itm/sso/misc/ldap-info-wrapper.c nil)) (point-min) (point-max) (car (split-string gzip -d)) t t nil (cdr (split-string gzip -d)))))’...done
Tramp: Inserting ‘/scp:helium:/home/norman/checkouts/itm/sso/misc/ldap-info-wrapper.c’...done
```

Then it hangs.  I `C-g`, and then get:

```
Tramp: Checking ‘vc-registered’ for /scp:helium:/home/norman/checkouts/itm/sso/misc/ldap-info-wrapper.c...done
Tramp: Inserting ‘/scp:helium:/home/norman/checkouts/itm/sso/misc/ldap-info-wrapper.c’...done
Quit
```

I make a change to the file, and save it:

```
Saving file /scp:helium:/home/norman/checkouts/itm/sso/misc/ldap-info-wrapper.c...
Tramp: Opening connection for helium using scp...
Tramp: Sending command ‘exec ssh   -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none helium’
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...done
Tramp: Found remote shell prompt on ‘helium’
Tramp: Opening connection for helium using scp...done
Tramp: Encoding local file ‘/var/folders/f5/vh0d0ls94_j5s4bv49sz90s40000gn/T/tramp.Rn8nOp.c’ using ‘(lambda (beg end) (let ((coding-system-for-write (quote binary)) (coding-system-for-read (quote binary))) (apply (quote tramp-call-process-region) (quote (tramp-file-name scp nil nil helium nil /home/norman/checkouts/itm/sso/misc/ldap-info-wrapper.c nil)) beg end (car (split-string gzip)) t t nil (cdr (split-string gzip)))) (base64-encode-region (point-min) (point-max)))’...done
```

It hangs again.  Again `C-g`, then:

```
Wrote /scp:helium:/home/norman/checkouts/itm/sso/misc/ldap-info-wrapper.c
Quit
```

It appears that it has indeed written the file before it hangs, so I don't lose any data by cancelling the operation.

This happens on two different remote machines (a CentOS and a FreeBSD one).

The shell prompt in each case should be `PS1='$ '`, after the recommended/obvious `rc` test of `$TERM`.  I've set the `$SHELL` environment variable to `/bin/bash` in the Emacs process (why not...?).  I've confirmed that I do indeed get a `$` prompt, with no other junk (apart from the motd contents, which don't count as ‘junk’), when I ssh to that machine with a `dumb` terminal; and the debugging messages `Found remote shell prompt` do seem to corroborate this.

I've configured connection sharing as [occasionally recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588136/), but I do [understand](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Frequently-Asked-Questions) that Tramp carefully ignores that (and I'm mentioning it only to indicate that I've done my homework!).

I seem to have exhausted the suggested problems in the [TrampMode section of the Emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode#toc7) and the [Tramp manual FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Frequently-Asked-Questions).

The lines `Checking ‘vc-registered’` seem significant, since the problem appears to happen only for remote files which are under version control (Mercurial, in my case); I can read and write `remote:~/foo.txt` without problem.  However those lines aren't being reported, in the `*Messages*` buffer, as *failing*, and the hangs aren't adjacent to those lines in the buffer, in either case.  I can see some discussion of what *may* be this problem [from 2014](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2014-10/msg01232.html), but that thread appears to suggest that the fix is already committed (five years ago!).  I tried `(setq vc-handled-backends nil)` in the hope that this might turn off any Tramp cleverness in this area, but without effect.  The Tramp manual doesn't suggest that there is any particular cleverness in this area, in any case.

(*edit*) Further investigation shows that this *does* seem to be specific to version-controlled files.  If I copy the version-controlled file to another one, `wibble.c`, then I can open, edit, and write it exactly as I'd expect.  The messages there are:

```
Saving file /scp:helium:/home/norman/checkouts/itm/sso/misc/wibble.c...
Tramp: Opening connection for helium using scp...
Tramp: Sending command ‘exec ssh   -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none helium’
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...done
Tramp: Found remote shell prompt on ‘helium’
Tramp: Opening connection for helium using scp...done
Tramp: Encoding local file ‘/var/folders/f5/vh0d0ls94_j5s4bv49sz90s40000gn/T/tramp.ZGFIYd.c’ using ‘(lambda (beg end) (let ((coding-system-for-write (quote binary)) (coding-system-for-read (quote binary))) (apply (quote tramp-call-process-region) (quote (tramp-file-name scp nil nil helium nil /home/norman/checkouts/itm/sso/misc/wibble.c nil)) beg end (car (split-string env GZIP= gzip)) t t nil (cdr (split-string env GZIP= gzip)))) (base64-encode-region (point-min) (point-max)))’...done
Tramp: Decoding remote file ‘/scp:helium:/home/norman/checkouts/itm/sso/misc/wibble.c’ using ‘(openssl enc -d -base64 | env GZIP= gzip -d >%s)’...done
Wrote /scp:helium:/home/norman/checkouts/itm/sso/misc/wibble.c
```

Those messages don't appear to be any different from before (this is still with `tramp-verbose` set to 10).

The same happens with starting Emacs with `emacs -Q`.

I'm running Tramp 2.4.1.  The client Emacs is 26.1 (on macOS, and from the Nix distribution, to the extent that that might matter).

...and I'm very puzzled indeed.

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. If yes, please consider filing a bug report with a step-by-step recipe: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @Drew Good suggestion – thanks: I should have thought of that.  But exactly the same happens if I start with `-Q`.  I've edited the question to note that it does seem to be associated with version-controlled files. If no insight appears over the weekend, I'll have a go at a bug report on Monday (but it's now long past beer/home-time)

Comment: ;-) Sounds good.

Comment: There has been an error with Tramp and `vc-registered`, but I don't know whether this is related. See the thread starting at <http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2019-05/msg00010.html>. This problem is solved meanwhile in the repositories, if you have a chance to test Tramp from git ... Otherwise, I recommend to continue as proposed by Drew, write a bug report.

Comment: See https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=36090